# Нужно написать функцию которая чистит массив

Tags: javascript

Я что то запутался .

создать функцию которая принимает массив чисел первым аргументом и втом аргументом число которое указывает на то сколько раз каждая из цифр в массиве может повториться. пример вызова функции

//deleteNth([1,1,3,3,7,2,2,2,2], 3) -> результат новый массив [1, 1, 3, 3, 7, 2, 2, 2]

```
function delNum(arr, repiat) {
    let rez = arr;
    for (let x = 0; x < arr.length; x++) {
        for (let y = 0; y < rez.length; y++) {
            if (arr[x] === rez[y]) {
                let count = 1;
                if (count > repiat) {
                    rez.splice(x, 1);
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return rez;
}
```

console.log(delNum([21, 20, 2, 21, 21], 1));

Comment: Покажите, пожалуйста, Ваши наработки.

Comment: @ya.ymer честно говоря я несовсем понимаю алгоритм действий которые мне нужно сделать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Набросал решение, но не могу быть уверен в его корректности.

Вам следует перебрать массив через [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map), при этом сохраняя количество проходов по одному значению (не смог подобрать более понятную формулировку), затем, если это значение уже находится в массиве допустимое количество раз, заменяем его на `false` и через [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) фильтруем.

```js
/**
  * @param {Array} array
  * @param {Number} allowed
  **/

let ourArray  = [21, 20, 2, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 56, 27];

function removeDuplicates(array, allowed) {
  let count = {};
  return array.map(e => {
    if (!count.hasOwnProperty(e))
      count[e] = 0;
    
    count[e] += 1;
    
    return count[e] <= allowed ? e : false;
  }).filter(e => e !== false);
};

console.log(removeDuplicates(ourArray, 1));
console.log(removeDuplicates(ourArray, 2));
console.log(removeDuplicates(ourArray, 3));
```

Видимо, изначально задачу я понял неправильно. Использовать в своём решении цикл, мне кажется, не целесообразно - он в вашем примере просто сравнивает равны ли предыдущий и текущий элементы между собой, но поставленной задачи не выполняет.
 
Следующий пример позволяет добавлять в массив число только в том случае, если оно не повторяется подряд больше указанного количества раз. Документация по [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
function delNum(arr, repeat) {
  let used = 0, // число повторов одного числа
    rez = [];

  arr.reduce((p, c) => {
    used = p === c ? used + 1 : 1;
    if (used <= repeat)
      rez.push(c);

    return c;
  });

  return rez;
}

let array = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2];

console.log(delNum(array, 2));
```

В итоге ТС попросил реализовать через `for`, прикладываю такую реализацию тоже (однако, он полностью эквивалентен первому):

```js
function delNum(arr, repeat) {
  let usedWithCount = {},
    newArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
    if (usedWithCount.hasOwnProperty(arr[i]))
      usedWithCount[arr[i]] += 1;
    else
      usedWithCount[arr[i]] = 1;

    if (usedWithCount[arr[i]] > repeat)
      continue;

    newArr.push(arr[i]);

  }
  return newArr;
};

console.log(delNum([21, 20, 2, 21, 21, 20, 20, 20, 56, 27], 1)); // -> [21,20,2,56,27]
```

Comment: блин ну капец как сложно

Comment: а что сложного? Если непонятен какой-то момент, могу объяснить.

Comment: добавил наработку

Comment: дополнил ответ под вашу задачу.

Comment: переправил наработку

Comment: не изменилось ведь ничего...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82165/discussion-between-ya-ymer-and-dpi).

Comment: `reduce`, тоже является циклом.

Comment: @And, ох, хотел написать `for`. извините, отсутствие сна даёт о себе знать. правил.